# How do I properly wire GFCI outlets in parallel?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, outlets, gfci

I have two countertop outlets in my kitchen that I am in the process of replacing with new, GFCI-protected outlets. These two outlets are on a circuit together, and they are the only loads on that circuit. After wiring the new outlets up and testing them, I noticed an odd behavior. When tripping the "upstream" outlet, the "downstream" outlet does not receive any power. I assume this is because they are wired in series.

1. Is it possible to wire these two outlets in parallel so that when the "upstream" outlet trips, it won't cut off power to the "downstream" outlet?
2. Would this a wise thing to do?
3. Would it be up to code?
4. If so, how do I do it?

**Edit:** I realize now that I have confused series and parallel with inline and not inline. Thank you all for clearing that up *and* for such great answers!

Comment: I think you are confusing series and parallel, with inline and not inline.

Comment: One thing, as an aside; if your jurisdiction (state, municipality) has adopted the 2011 Nat'l Electrical Code as legally binding, then any outlets you install in your home must be tamper-resistant (it'll say TR on the face of the outlet) in addition to having to be GFCI-protected in kitchens, bathrooms, and other wet areas. If the GFCIs you bought don't have the temper-resistant shutters, it is illegal to install them even as replacements; return them and ask for tamper-resistant GFCIs.

Comment: @KeithS Interesting point. How can I check if my jurisdiction has adopted the 2011 NEC? Furthermore, how can I check that I don't have to be a licensed electrician in my jurisdiction to perform repairs in my own home? I've never considered that before.

Comment: @DrewSpickes You can check the [Adoption of the National Electrical Code® map](http://www.nema.org/stds/fieldreps/NECadoption/implement.cfm)

Comment: ... And call your county clerk. In the NEC and a majority of jurisdictions a homeowner is allowed to do their own electrical work, but a for-hire electrician must be licensed. Work of a certain scope, such as replacing your electrical panel, may be required to be permitted and/or inspected. Wiring a replacement plug generally doesn't qualify.

Comment: @KeithS I believe NEC 2008 had the TR requirement as well, but it wasn't written well. It was interpreted to only be required in *New* installs, while the intention was to cover *replacement* as well (see NEC 2008 406.11).  The section has been rewritten in 2011 to be more clear (see NEC 2011 406.12-14)

Comment: @Tester101: Right, the end result being that the 2008 code *as interpreted* only required TR for new installs.

Comment: @Tester101 This might be worthy of a separate question, but I'm in Georgia which is listed as adopting the 2011 NEC, and it's still kind of a pain to track down the TR receptacles in stores, and you trip over about 20 varieties of non-TR receps along the way. What gives?

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman if you're talking about stores like Home Depot and Lowes, you have to remember 1) they are not electrical supply companies, and 2) code does not say stores can't sell non-TR receptacles.  Big box stores do not always keep up with codes, and may continue to carry non-TR receptacles until they are out of stock and/or the code is adopted nation wide.

Comment: @Tester101 Good point about the stores just following nationwide trends. In the mean time, it's frustrating if you are aware of the move to TR receps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

GFCI receptacles have two sets of contacts, `line`, and `load`.  The `Line` side of the receptacle is used to power the device, while the `load` side is used to power other devices down the line.  Any device connected to the `load` side of a GFCI receptacle, will be protected by the GFCI receptacle.

For example, if you have a setup like this (which I assume you have).

[image]

There is no need to have a GFCI receptacle as the second receptacle, since it will already be protected by the first GFCI receptacle. Because of this, if the first device trips all devices on the `load` side will not be powered (as you have noticed).

You can use pigtails to connect the receptacles like this.

[image]

But in a setup like this, you'll be required to have a GFCI receptacle at both outlets. The devices down stream are no longer protected by the first GFCI receptacle, because they are not fed by the `load` side of the device.

FYI:
*This is what it would look like if the receptacles were wired in series.*
[image]

Comment: BTW, the GFCIs shown in these pics, with the red and black buttons, are no longer code-compliant; you can't buy them and should not install them. New GFCIs have buttons matching the color of the outlet, and are "self-testing" so they will automatically fail open and refuse to reset when they can no longer provide protection. Virtually nobody heeds the "test monthly" instructions on these outlets, hence the change, though the new GFCIs do still have Test buttons and do still say that (ounce of prevention...).

Comment: @KeithS Just picked one up at the local big box store about a week ago. [SmartLockPro 15-amp GFCI with Red/Black Buttons](http://www.homedepot.com/Electrical-Electrical-Outlets-Plugs/h_d1/N-25ecodZ5yc1vZbm4n/R-202026816/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=gfci&storeId=).  What makes them not code compliment?

Comment: ... I guess I stand corrected. The guy at Lowe's who mans the electrical aisles said that if I was looking for a GFCI with red/black buttons that I was out of luck, because the designs that had the colored buttons didn't self-test and so were no longer compliant. He was half-right; the first-gen GFCIs all had contrasting buttons and didn't self-test, and Cooper Wiring (which supplies 90% of Lowes' electrical aisle) doesn't seem to have a single outlet with contrasting test/reset.

Comment: Now, because the outlets are not TR, they actually are non-compliant in areas that have adopted 2011 NEC, but that's not the reason I originally stated :P

Comment: Heh. My wife made it a requirement for the test and reset buttons to match the outlet. I'll double-check to make sure they are self-testing. Thank you all for the useful information!

Comment: If you just bought them, even some years ago, they should be fine. It should say on the box or the cutsheet something to the effect that the outlet will not reset if miswired or if GFCI protection is compromised (such as the outlet reaching end-of-life).

Comment: I think keeping the two outlets not inline would be ideal for my purposes. I'm willing to pay a bit more for both GFCI outlets and spend a bit more installation time to ensure that the two GFCIs will trigger independently of one another and not affect one another. That way, my whole kitchen wall won't go dead if something trips - just the offending outlet.

Comment: If the GFCI outlets have the captive nut style connection then you don't need the wire nuts.

Comment: @BradGilbert Maybe I'm "old school", but I find one wire per terminal is less confusing.  Just my preference I guess.

Comment: @BradGilbert "Captive nut style"? Maybe I haven't seen this or didn't note it as such. Any pics?

Comment: Also called "EZ-Wire" or similar. Basically instead of curling the wire around the screw on the outside of the plug body, by turning the screw you loosen a plate on the inside of the plug, then you insert a straight, stripped wire into the back of the plug and screw it down. Most such designs allow for two wires per screw/plate, because this kind of design can easily handle it and because it's often called for.

Comment: Also called screw-and-clamp.  They are not push/backstab connections, but the wire nestles in a hole right behind the screw, and is clamped when the screw is tightened. These typically support 2 wires per screw.  **You must not do this for grounds (and neutrals in MWBCs). Those must be pigtailed so they are not severed by removing the device.

Answer (score 11):

This is the correct behavior.  You only need 1 GFCI outlet per circuit (assuming it's at the beginning of the line and the rest of the outlets are loads).

They are correctly wired in parallel - if they were in series, you wouldn't get the correct voltage at the other outlets when there is any type of load present.

Comment: This is very useful information, but it doesn't fully answer my question. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 5):

1. It is possible. You have to ask yourself if that's what you REALLY want; the design of a GFCI outlet is such that it will protect everything "downstream" of it and 99% of the time this is a very good thing.
2. Again, consider whether you REALLY want to not have GFCI protection on these outlets (and whether it's allowable by code). Sometimes it's a no-brainer; say your fridge is on your kitchen appliance branch circuit (perfectly acceptable). If the GFCI for countertop outlets trips while you're away from home, you don't want your fridge cutting out. So, you can often keep the fridge running by strategically placing unchained GFCIs in the circuit around the fridge outlet, bypassing protection for the fridge. Same for the microwave. BUT, most devices, such as your DW and disposer (those can be on the same branch as the countertop outlets IF the home was built or last reno'ed before 1996) require GFCI protection anyway along with all countertop outlets. Even the fridge should probably have GFCI protection if it has water/ice dispensers; it should just have its OWN GFCI, which trips when the fridge itself shorts and not the toaster next to it.
3. Code does not specifically require everything downstream of an installed GFCI outlet to be protected by that GFCI outlet, and so technically, bypassing protection is allowed. However, code does apply to individual outlets; any receptacle outlet within 6 feet of a sink, tub, toilet, shower or other "wet" area MUST be GFCI-protected either by having a GFCI outlet there, or having one upstream that has this outlet as part of its "load". So, if bypassing GFCI at any given point would make any downstream outlet non-compliant, you'll need to either suck it up and protect the whole line, or install a second GFCI further downstream to protect the needed outlet. As GFCIs start at about $11 and run up to $25 depending on a variety of factors (15/20A, TR/WR, EZ-wire, color, style, brand, region) putting multiple GFCIs on a circuit can become an expensive way to wire your home (though probably less expensive than rewiring the circuit completely).
4. If you really do want it this way, it's accomplished by connecting both line AND load wires to the "line" terminals on the GFCI outlet. You will not be able to use the "load" terminals to connect wires as those will cut out when the GFCI does. The best way to do this is to wire-nut the line and load wires together (hot separate from neutral of course) along with a third piece of insulated wire to connect to the GFCI terminal. The following will also work but licensed electricians may cringe; firmly screw both the line and load wires onto the line terminal (I see this all the time when working with daisy-chained switches in multi-gang boxes so it can't be THAT bad). This works perfectly fine if you use "EZ-Wire" GFCI outlets; they have a plate that clamps down with the screw to hold wires so you don't have to curl around the screw terminal. Most of these have holes or notches for two wires per terminal and they're very secure.

Comment: Thank you for addressing each of the points individually and providing insightful comments on the other answers!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a bathroom outlet that provides power to my entire bedroom. I have no idea who came up with that idea but when I put in a GFCI and realized that the load would cut off power to the bedroom, I threw up in my mouth a little. I plan on following your instructions for #4 because that seems to make the most sense to me.

Comment: @JoePhilllips If parts of your bedroom are within 6 ft of the outside edge of the bathroom sink, then those parts do need to be GFCI-protected. The 6 ft rule doesn't take partitions into account; it's just a flat 6-ft extent in all directions.

Answer (score 3):

GFCIs come marked with two sets of terminals.  One pair is marked LINE and the other marked load.

Typically, you would connect the line voltage to the Line pair, and you would run from the load pair to any downstream outlets and or lights.  The load pair of terminals is already protected, so you need not use GFCIs further down the chain.  So, if the GFCI outlet is the first item in the chain, everything downstream will also be turned off in a fault situation (As if the breaker tripped.)

What you need to do in your situation is to pigtail wires in the box **before** it connects to the GFCI, and to run a cable to the next outlet, which will now be unprotected unless you also use a GFCI outlet. (SEE TESTER101's answer with MSPAINT!!!)  I believe the code says GFCI's are required within 6 feet from any sink.  I go a bit further (9', with some common sense), to ensure that I can't touch the toaster with an 18 inch cord, with my 10" chef's knife while touching the sink.  I also have stainless steel appliances which look like an attractive ground to me, so I treat them as if they were sinks.

Comment: Hey Chris. I'm just wondering if pigtailing wires is necessary or can you just put the load in one hole and the line in the other on the outlet itself (see the leviton 7599-kw as an example)

Comment: It's possible, Although I'd rather not use the quick connects.  I like the idea of torquing a screw down to hold the wire.  Also, pigtails make it easier for the next person to swap something out should the need arise.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I'll wire up some pigtails as long as they fit in the box

Comment: There are some places where you're required to wire things up so that removing the device doesn't break the circuit. I don't recall specifically, because I always pigtail devices in anyway, so I'm always in compliance with that requirement.